# Away3d stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT; not working?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, away3d

I started my application with

```
[SWF(width="2560", height="720", frameRate="60", backgroundColor="#000000")]
```

And I have two View3D, the left one is at (0,0) with size (1280*720), the right one is at (1280,0) with the same size(1280*720).

And I also have this line:

```
 stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
```

However, it seems like it didn't change my aspect ratio to let the entire application be visible. about half part of the right View3D is out of window.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try `StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL`, it should maintain aspect ratio and show all like it implies.

Comment: Hey Todd, Thanks, I've tried this method, but it's not working.